# What is the difference between a condition and a criterion?

Tags: terminology

One can argue that a *criterion* is any *condition* phrased in a question manner:

> Does the applicant have a BSc in computer science?

Although, most criterions I ever came across were not phrased as a question.

---

Alternatively, one can argue that a *criterion* is a private case of *condition*, were it is a "necessary condition" versus a "unnecessary condition"; for example:

- A necessary condition to get the job is a BSc in computer science
- A unnecessary condition to get the job is 5 years experience with Drupal

Filling both conditions enlarges the chance to get the job but do not totally guarantee acceptance, and yet splitting a condition to "necessary" and "unnecessary" quite destroys the common meaning of "condition".

---

What is the difference between a condition and a criterion?

Comment: Questions about use and meanings of words are not on-topic on this site, they are better suited for [English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/). "Condition" has a very broad scope, while criterion is, more specifically, a set of conditions used to identify or characterize something definitively.

Comment: @Conifold if you are a mod here I suggest you to consider to migrate this to English SE which I can't do without duplicating content because I cannot delete the question (to later re-publish a backup of it in English SE).

Comment: There is a delete action link under the tags, along with edit, share, etc.

Comment: @Conifold me as a guest don't have it under the tags.

Comment: Don't worry about it then, it will be closed when the votes accumulate. I am not a moderator, they have a diamond symbol next to their username.

Comment: This proves you were told something about conditional statements that is NOT ALWAYS TRUE. It was only true on Thursdays. More than likely that definition came from math where people assume that all cases of an if . . . Then. . . Means necessary or sufficient.  In your case the condition or criterion seem to indicate the MINIMUM acceptable cases not a necessity. You can't rule out favoritism will never occur. For some people a degree maybe needed. Other people might still get the job. Both are unnecessary you interpreted incorrectly. To prove necessity you have to rule out other options.

Comment: @Logikal by that logic you would say that only if the interviewer decides that the candidate is the right man for the job a necessary "condition" was filled, correct?

Comment: @guesto, no I would say there is no absolute or guarantee that the right candidate must be hired. There is too much subjectivity in ". . . only if the interviewer decides . . . " There is no universal standard he is applying to all is there? Well that is not clear so the reasoning I did HOLDS. Someone else going the other direction in reasoning MAY ACCIDENTALLY be correct. Please be aware being accidentally correct and knowing what you are doing are two distinct things. Necessary in the objective sense means ONE WAY. There are no two ways or three ways, etc.Absolutes can only have one solution

Comment: @Logikal `Please be aware being accidentally correct and knowing what you are doing are two distinct things` I know that ; I think that with a bit of philosophy (especially fatalism) one can say that the interviewer's decision is the only necessary condition to be accepted (if it happens).

Comment: @guesto, you are misusing the term NECCESSARY!  You can't RATIONALLY say x is necessary and there is more than one solution. To say you must be have a BSC DEGREE is necessary means it should be impossible for a human being to hold the position or job without the degree. You can't guarantee that there will be no exceptions or extraordinary circumstances where the requirements are lifted. This is NOT a NECESSARY anything. People could change the rules on a whim. NECESSARY doesn't mean politics or some human has control. It is necessary to believe in Christ to be saved for instance. One solution.

Comment: @guesto, I think we can both agree the CORRECT TERM here is sufficient.  Sufficient means the minimum acceptable standards to get the job. We ought to both agree the necessary here means all people who meet the criteria or standard MUST BE HIRED. That my friend would what necessary means. If 10 people with degrees apply all 10 must be hired. It is reasonable to think one job is available to the right candidate not all who qualify. This is why SUFFICIENT is the correct term in the context of the job.

Comment: @Logikal with how to you essentially defined necessary here than I can understand why you say that anyone with a "necessary" background should be hired; but if I use `sufficient` instead, does it apply to both the "strong" criterion for BSc and the "weak" criterion for experience with a particular software?

Comment: @guesto, absolutely you can & typically you should take the sufficient context in most cases. When you say something is NECESSARY there is no way to avoid it. If there is more than one alternative as a solution then the context is SUFFICIENT.  SUFFICIENT MEANS there is more than one way to resolve the issue or multiple solutions.   The job interviewers are not hiring all who qualify. We agree on that don't we?  If you understand conditional propositions you would understand implications are disjunction. If p then q can & often means ~not p or q is possible.

Comment: How would you define both "requirements" or "conditions" (?) for the job? How would you categorize them?

Comment: and BTW @Logikal how you use the term necessary surprised me - I never came across such usage in practice; perhaps it's common in formal logic literature.

Comment: @guesto, the term SUFFICENT means the minimum POSSIBLE solutions. Plus there could be other subjective or emotional issues that can eliminate the rule or criteria. Should all human beings wear facial masks to prevent covid? If it is necessary then there should be ZERO  human beings should be walking out in public as some elected authorities have been. So clearly it is NOT A MUST! Wearing a mask is  SUFFICIENT to prevent the spreading the covid disease. I don't doubt you would agree that this usage is used MORE FREQUENTLY than any other usage. What do you mean you never came across such usage?

Comment: First, I am not a native English speaker so I am biased about Enlgish; second, in regards to the distinction you have made: I think that in my mind, many times people said "necessary" but meant "sufficient".

Comment: @guesto, I would recommend you note the distinction between necessity and sufficient. In common slang usage most English speakers mean sufficient.  If you are not sure what the person speaking or writing means then you OUGHT to ask them specifically.  If there is multie ways to get to the goal you know it means sufficient. If there is exactly one solution with no exceptions or special cases that are different then you know you must follow the directions they give. Otherwise you would get the message wrong. Bet 90 percent they mean this is only one way to reach the goal out of many ways.